# How to fix unresolved imports for Mapbox 9.5.0 in AndroidX using Java

Tags: java, android, sdk, mapbox

I am in the process of creating an Android navigation application using the Mapbox SDK (version 9.5.0 currently) and I have successfully been able to initialize a map view as well as track the user's current location. Up until this point I have had no issues with unresolved import statements or any real problems. The feature I am currently working on is to allow the user to select a location point on the map, which will place a map marker on that point and return the coordinates of the marker. To incorporate this feature I have been following the Mapbox Documentation, specifically [this tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/location-picker/).

Now that I have added this new code to my application I have found a few issues, there are quite a number of objects that I am trying to make use of that can not be resolved, to look into this issue I went to my import statements at the top of my java file and found a few imports that are not working properly, namely:

```
import com.mapbox.api.geocoding.v5.GeocodingCriteria;
import com.mapbox.api.geocoding.v5.MapboxGeocoding;
import com.mapbox.api.geocoding.v5.models.CarmenFeature;
import com.mapbox.api.geocoding.v5.models.GeocodingResponse;
```

The above imports all have a red line under *"api"* and give the error: *" Cannot resolve symbol 'api' "* . Some other erroneous imports are:

```
import com.mapbox.core.exceptions.ServicesException;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import timber.log.Timber;
```

I am not sure why all of these specific imports are unresolved, as all of my other Mapbox imports haven't given me any issues yet. I suspect it might be a missing dependency or implementation in my Gradle files, but I have followed the documentation guide to be best of my ability so unless I missed something vital I am not sure what the cause might be. Here are the Mapbox dependencies and implementations that I added to my grade files:
Project-level build.gradle:

```
maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                username = 'mapbox'
                password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: "my secret password"
            }
        }
```

and in my app-level build.gradle:

```
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.5.0'
```

If anyone has an idea of what my issue could be, I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: for test case set `implementation('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.3.0') {
        exclude group: 'group_name', module: 'module_name'
    }`

Comment: Try rebuilding the project.

Comment: I will try that, thank you kindly. I would just like to know if I should replace 'group_name' and 'module_name' with anything or should I leave as is?

Comment: okay, just set `implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.3.0'`. Then clean-rebuild

Comment: I just tried changing the version to 9.3.0 and then clean-rebuilding the project and it has not changed anything unfortunately. Perhaps I am missing an additional dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick with Maps SDK `9.5.0`

Not needed because you can just use regular logging (e.g. `log.e` rather than `Timber.e`), but Timber can be downloaded via: https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber#download

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/location-picker uses `MapboxGeocoding`, which is the Mapbox Java SDK's wrapper around the Mapbox Geocoding API. You need to install the `services` module to use `MapboxGeocoding`: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/overview/#installation & https://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/overview/#available-packages. This should resolve the

```
import com.mapbox.api.geocoding.v5.GeocodingCriteria;
import com.mapbox.api.geocoding.v5.MapboxGeocoding;
import com.mapbox.api.geocoding.v5.models.CarmenFeature;
import com.mapbox.api.geocoding.v5.models.GeocodingResponse;
```

and

```
import com.mapbox.core.exceptions.ServicesException;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
```

Heads up that there's also the Places Plugin https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/places/, which has a place picker functionality (https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/examples/place-picker/) that's more polished than https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/location-picker

Answer (score -1):

```
MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN="PASTE_YOUR_SECRET_TOKEN_HERE" instead of MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN=PASTE_YOUR_SECRET_TOKEN_HERE.
```

Just try this, in my case the quotes was the problem .Just removed quotes and it worked